# Why does this char array Seg Fault

Tags: c, arrays, char, segmentation-fault

Can anyone explain to me why when initializing a char array, if the array size is left blank, like this

```
char str1[] = "Hello";
```

the program will seg fault, but if it is specified like this

```
char str1[10] = "Hello";
```

it works fine.

Here is the full program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char concat_string(char str[], char str2[], char destination[], unsigned int bufferSize);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int bufferSize = 64;
    // Both str1 and str2 must be defined
    // or else the program will seg fault.
    char str1[] = "Hello ";
    char str2[] = "World";
    char concatenatedString[bufferSize];

    concat_string(str1,str2,concatenatedString,bufferSize);

    printf("The concatenated string is: \n%s\n", concatenatedString);
    return 0;
}


char concat_string(char str[], char str2[], char destination[], unsigned int bufferSize)
{
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    strncat(str, str2, bufferSize);
    strncpy(buffer,str, bufferSize);
    strncpy(destination,buffer,bufferSize);
    return *destination;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow right here in your `concat_string` function:

```
strncat(str, str2, bufferSize);
```

Your `str` only has room for seven bytes and it is already full before you try to append `str2` to it. You're getting lucky with this:

```
char str1[10] = "Hello";
```

as you still don't have enough space allocated to append `"World"` to it; you're also missing the trailing space on this version of `str1` but that's not relevant to your segfault. Your `concat_string` should be copying `str` directly to `destination` and then appending `str2` to `destination`. This would also avoid altering the `str` and `str2` arguments and that would be more polite; you also don't pass the sizes of the `str` and `str1` arrays so there's no way to know if there is room to append anything to them.

Comment: @FrozenWasteland: We all start out as idiots. Make mistaeks, learn lessons, rinse, and repeat.